# Need help adding items to list array and finding the position or index in the list in Java with Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, arraylist

I'm navigating to a page and getting all of the items in the header of a table. I'm trying to put them in a list so that I can then find out where "Attempt Date" is in the list.

```
List<String> header = new ArrayList<>();
List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//tablehead"));
for (WebElement element : elements) {
   header.add(element.getText());
}
System.out.println("The header values are: " + header);
System.out.println(header.indexOf("Attempt Date"));
```

When I execute this, the system output is:

The header values are: [File Name Attempt Date User File Type Batch Operation]

-1

What I would expect to see is [File Name, Attempt Date, User, File Type, Batch Operation] and that it would tell me that "Attempt Date" is the 2nd item in the list.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you print all the `element.getText()` within the loop(in different lines)? My guess would be that the strings are not equal(space or some other special character difference) hence the index is not found for the element.

Comment: By looking at the header list output, it seems that it is a single string stored in the list. By looking at the code, I doubt that `driver.findElements(By.xpath("//tablehead"))` returning one web element having text as `File Name Attempt Date User File Type Batch Operation`.
When list stores list of string, they are separated by commas (,) but in your case, its a simple string. Please do consider writing locator to access each column of header

Comment: Your suggestion made me think to change the locator to be more targeted and use //tablehead/tr/th since each of the items I want to get are held in a "th" tag.

This locator now returns a comma separated list like what I was expecting to see, and it gives me the correct index value.
Thanks for the suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

To get the position, you can implement something like this form this java reference

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html

class BreakDemo {
public static void main(String[] args) {

```
    int[] arrayOfInts = 
        { 32, 87, 3, 589,
          12, 1076, 2000,
          8, 622, 127 };
    int searchfor = 12;

    int i;
    boolean foundIt = false;

    for (i = 0; i < arrayOfInts.length; i++) {
        if (arrayOfInts[i] == searchfor) {
            foundIt = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (foundIt) {
        System.out.println("Found " + searchfor + " at index " + i);
    } else {
        System.out.println(searchfor + " not in the array");
    }
}
```

}